# Converting Native Query Result To POJO : Error on boolean field

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I had a use case where I had to run a native query. I was able to run it successfully but when I am trying to convert the resultset to dto I am getting errors on boolean fields.
Since I am using MySQL, the boolean value column is bit(1) in the database.

Here is the code for the wrapper

```
public interface DownloadDetails {
   Boolean getBooleanField();  //Doesnot work but why?
   Integer getBooleanFieldAsInt(); //Works but needs explicit check to boolean in code 
   Long getLongField();
}
```

Native Query :

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = CUSTOM_QUERY)
List<DownloadDetails> getDownloadDetails();
```

Now when I try to do something like `downloadDetails.getBooleanField()` it does not work and gives  an error as

> Projection type must be an interface!

Anything which I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I did something like this

```
public interface DownloadDetails {
   String getBooleanFieldAsString();
   Long getLongField();

   default Boolean getBooleanFieldAsBoolean(){
      return BooleanUtils.toBoolean(getBooleanFieldAsString());
   }
```

}

This is the best possible and the neatest way workaround I could think of. Also if you want to use this interface for directly sending the response back(which you might consider avoiding), use `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty("customName")`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need a native query exactly, but maybe you can do with using [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(DownloadEntity.class)
public interface DownloadDetails {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    @Mapping("CAST_BOOLEAN(booleanStringAttribute)")
    String getBoolean();
    Long getLongField();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`DownloadDetails a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, DownloadDetails.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<DownloadDetails> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!